# Disable save button when save is executed

Tags: lightning-web-components, javascript, html

I'm new to Salesforce Development.
I'm stuck in my code from past few hours.

I would like to disable the button after record is saved and it should enable when the user enters another values in the field.

I have researched about it but got nothing on web.

Here's my HTML

```
<div class="slds-text-align_center">
    <lightning-button
        label="Save"
        onclick={handleTimesheet}
        disabled={disableButton}
    ></lightning-button>
</div>
```

In JS,button is disabled when the last name is empty, I want this as well as, disable the button when the save is executed.

```
get disableButton() {
    return !this.lastName;
}
```

It would be a great help.

Thank in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am still learning the lwc. :) But let me give it a try.
Define a boolean variable called as isSaved. Set it to false initially. Change your disableButton method like this:

```
get disableButton() {
    return !this.lastName || this.isSaved;
}
```

Then in the Save method, when you have a success, just set the isSaved as true like this:

```
this.isSaved=true;
```

Comment: It's working on disable button after saving the button stays disable while creating another record.

Comment: @PrinceSharma You will also need to have code that detects a new change (e.g. an `onchcnage` handler) and re-sets this property to false.

Comment: @KeithC it helped. Thank You!

Comment: @Shailesh instead of `this.isSaved=true` it should be `this.isSaved=false`. Thank you!